# Relative Imports in Python correct syntax and requirements

Tags: python

I know this horse has been flogged countless times but none of the answers answer my question

My folder structure is as follows

```
/pdocs
    __init__.py (empty)
    file1.py
    tester.py
    Test/
        __init__.py (empty)
        file2.py
```

file1.py is as follows

```
class file1:
    def sayhi():
        print "hi from parent"
```

file2.py is as follows

```
from ... import file1
class file2:
    def sayhitoo():
        print "Hi from child"
```

tester.py is as follows

```
from Test.file2 import file2
sayhi()
sayhitoo()
```

Tryin to run tester.py I get

```
"from ... import file1"
"ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package"
```

What does this mean. What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to import from "two levels up" -- that's what the three dots in `...` mean.  You're importing from just **one** level up, so, use `..` instead.

There are other problems too -- e.g, after importing `file2`, you could call `file2.sayhitoo()`, but what you're trying to call instead is a **bareword** (unqualified) `sayhitoo`, which won't work (I predict a `NameError`).  Same, squared, in the attempt to call bareword `sayhi`.  But, these are yet further errors besides the one you're asking about:-).

Comment: Yes, yes I realized that. I just quickly put tester.py together. I know it isn't error free. In any case removing all dots from the import works. how is that?

Comment: And I got it. :). These __init__.py just define a diretory hierarchy with the root folder being the default path. Accessing any sub folder we need use dot notations.

Comment: if you're in the parent directory of pdocs, and import pdocs as a package, `>>> from pdocs import tester`, the `from .. import`in `file2.py` will work (and you'll instead get `NameError: name 'sayhi' is not defined`).  If instead of **importing** `tester` from the `pdocs` package, you're running it directly with the Python interpreter, or you're in directory `pdocs` to start, then the `pdocs` package is never constructed in memory in that Python run, so `file2` can't import from "the parent package" `pdocs`... because there **is** no such parent package:-)